# Azure upload blob with tokes sas

Tags: c#, azure, upload, storage

I've recently upgrade Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement Nuget package from 0.9.0 version to 0.12.0 version and I'm having some issues in my code... with previous version it's running fine.

```
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri(sConnString)); 
...
var task = TransferManager.UploadAsync(pathFile, blockBlob, null, context, CancellationToken.None);                
task.Wait();
```

I had to changed blob definition into:

```
CloudBlob blockBlob = new CloudBlob(new Uri(sConnString));
```

But now I receive this error from UploadAsync:
**One or more errors occurred. (The given blob type Unspecified is not supported.)**

Before upgrading DataMovement library it was working fine. 
What happened with latest version? How can I solve?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why are you using `CloudBlob` instead of `CloudBlockBlob`?

Comment: You're right! I made a mistake. Now it seems working.

Comment: @GauravMantri please post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

To make the answer visible to others, I'm summarizing the answer shared in comment as below:

The issue was resovled by using CloudBlockBlob instead of CloudBlob.